# App Engine second upload to Blobstore not working

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2, blobstore

I have a form whose data is asynchronously uploaded to Blobstore. When the upload is completed, the backend page outputs another `blobstore.get_upload_url()` to use for a second upload.

However, when the second upload is performed, it gives a `POST http://localhost:13080/_ah/upload/ah1kZXZ-YXZpc2JlcmdhbW8tMTQ2OTk2MTI5MTQ0OXIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICA_IoLDA 404 (Not Found)` error

Here's the code (JS):

```
$.ajax({
          url: upload_url,
          data: formData,

          contentType: false,
          processData: false,

          success: function (data) {
            upload_url = data.url;  
            formData = new FormData();
          },
          async: true,
          method: 'POST',

});
```

Here's the backend:

```
class InserisciDomandaHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):

        # ... uploads additional data to Datastore

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        obj = {
            'url': blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload_photo'),
          } 
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

I checked the new url and it is different than the old one. Additionally, the new url seems valid.

Why does it give me a 404 error? Thanks

EDIT:
The url seems valid but, when used both in production and in local, it is not treated as valid by App Engine. So, although it "intuitively" makes sense, it doesn't make sense in practice.

Comment: What triggers the second upload? Should your code be modifying `upload_url` with the new value?

Comment: When a user successfully uploads data through jQuery ajax, the backend page outputs the new URL which is used in 'success' to modify the upload_url for a second upload. The second upload, however, gives a 404 error.

Comment: Sorry about that second question. I was blind! I see that now. But as for my first question: the second upload must happen after some further user interaction, maybe re-filling out a form and then clicking a  button?

Comment: Does the same happens if instead of calling `create_upload_url()` inside the `post` method of handler inheriting `BlobstoreUploadHandler` you reply with a url obtainded ahead of time from a differrent context? Or if you wait a bit on the client side before trying the second upload? Trying to determine if the blobstore operation isn't somehow context-sensitive (intentionally or not) or maybe it just takes some time from when the url is produced and when the blobstore actually becomes ready the upload?

Comment: @EricSimonton Yes, the user has to refill the form. But that only means resetting FormData() and appending the new data to it, other than changing the upload URL.

Comment: @DanCornilescu The same problem happens even if I use another handler which is specifically designed for outputting the new URL. That means another jQuery Ajax calling the target URL which outputs only the URL and does nothing else. The alternative I have now used is refreshing the page as soon as everything is completed. Still, it bothers me that I'm finding such a weird problem.

Comment: Did you try increasing the time between getting the url and posting to it?